# Why does pfSense require a DNS access list entry when all interfaces are selected?

Tags: firewall, dns, pfsense

- Netgate 4100
- v23.05-RELEASE

The DNS Resolver was only working on LAN 1 but not LAN 3 (physical nics, not vlans).  I added an access list rule as suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PFSENSE/comments/et0bmz/comment/ffdsxqx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) to grant LAN 3 access and now everything works as expected.

Why was this necessary?  In the DNS Resolver settings, all interfaces are selected as shown below.  The other user in the Reddit link even mentions that adding the access list entry shouldn't be necessary.  My firewall rules for LAN 3 are wide open as well.  What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the access list entry and added an "allow" firewall rule for LAN 3 to access UDP port 53 on the "This Firewall" destination above the LAN 3 -> any rule.  Not sure why that was necessary but it seems to work.  Seems redundant to say, "Allow UDP 53 then allow everything" but that's another question.

Comment: It's not sufficient to bind a service - a firewall's logic is that by default, all traffic is denied, even to itself. So, unless you explicitly permit a packet it's going to be dropped.

Comment: Hi, Zac67, thanks for the comment.  What I find confusing is that I already had a rule that allowed everything (pictured above).  Why do I need a DNS-specific rule when all protocols (including UDP) and all ports (including 53) are already covered by the "*" rule?